# Soap UI assertions: The content doesnt match as per the regular expression format

Tags: groovy, soapui, soap-client

I am seeing the error related to regular expression as the format doesn’t match.

> Error: textReplacements_helpTextEnglish does not match expected format. Error field: [Singular (shampoo, bank, car). Consumer friendly language (car vs automotive)., Capture the level the ad is intended to work at (Coke, Diet Coke)., â€˜brand of category nameâ€™ singular (shampoo, bank, car). Consumer friendly language (car vs automotive). Change, or even remove, â€˜brand ofâ€™ if needed.] /RegEx: ^[a-zA-Z0-9@!#$%^&*()-:?/'""-_ ]*$. Expression: textReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk. Values: textReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk = false

Code

```
assert !messageExchange.responseHeaders["X-Powered-By"]
assert !messageExchange.responseHeaders["X-AspNet-Version"]
assert !messageExchange.responseHeaders["Server"]


// Script to verify content for all elements
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// get response
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def values = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def quotas = values.quotas
def textReplacements = values.textReplacements
def listReplacements = values.listReplacements
def qlibExportValidations = values.qlibExportValidations
def flatQuestions = values.flatQuestions
def regexPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@!#$%^&*()-:?\/'""-_ ]*$/

def item

// initialize values
def IdOk = true
def qlib_questionnaire_idOk = true
def qlib_questionnaire_version_idOk = true
def languageOk = true
def qlib_producttemplate_idOk = true
def wave_idOk = true
def study_keyOk = true
def last_updatedOk = true
def Quotas_idOk = true
def Quotas_nameOk = true
def Quotas_titleOk = true
def Quotas_isSystemOk = true
def Quotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk = true
def Quotas_isDefaultQuotaOk = true
def Quotas_hideQuotaInUIOk = true
def Quotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk = true
def Quotas_setting_dependenciesOk = true
def Quotas_attributezOk = true
def textReplacements_keyOk = true
def textReplacements_isHiddenOk = true
def textReplacements_displayNameOk = true
def textReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk = true
def textReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk = true
def textReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk = true
def textReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk = true
def textReplacements_isDisabledOk = true
def listReplacements_keyOk = true
def listReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk = true
def listReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk = true
def listReplacements_completedOk = true
def listReplacements_metRequirementsOk = true
def listReplacements_last_modified_byOk = true
def listReplacements_last_modified_dateOk = true
def listReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk = true
def listReplacements_typeOk = true
def listReplacements_displayNameOk = true
def listReplacements_itemNameSingleOk = true
def listReplacements_itemNamePluralOk = true
def listReplacements_descriptionOk = true
def listReplacements_shortDescriptionOk = true
def listReplacements_disabledOk = true
def listReplacements_user_msgOk = true
def listReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk = true
def listReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk = true
def qlibExportValidations_statusOk = true
def flatQuestions_moduleIdOk = true
def flatQuestions_contentTypeOk = true
def flatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk = true
def flatQuestions_variableNameOk = true
def flatQuestions_groupNameOk = true
def flatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk = true
def flatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk = true
def flatQuestions_titleOk = true
def flatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk = true
def flatQuestions_isHiddenOk = true
def flatQuestions_isSelectedOk = true

def errorIdOk 
def errorqlib_questionnaire_idOk 
def errorqlib_questionnaire_version_idOk 
def errorlanguageOk 
def errorqlib_producttemplate_idOk 
def errorwave_idOk 
def errorstudy_keyOk 
def errorlast_updatedOk 
def errorQuotas_idOk 
def errorQuotas_nameOk 
def errorQuotas_titleOk 
def errorQuotas_isSystemOk 
def errorQuotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk 
def errorQuotas_isDefaultQuotaOk 
def errorQuotas_hideQuotaInUIOk 
def errorQuotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk 
def errorQuotas_setting_dependenciesOk 
def errorQuotas_attributezOk 
def errortextReplacements_keyOk 
def errortextReplacements_isHiddenOk 
def errortextReplacements_displayNameOk 
def errortextReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk 
def errortextReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk 
def errortextReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk 
def errortextReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk 
def errortextReplacements_isDisabledOk 
def errorlistReplacements_keyOk 
def errorlistReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk 
def errorlistReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk 
def errorlistReplacements_completedOk 
def errorlistReplacements_metRequirementsOk 
def errorlistReplacements_last_modified_byOk 
def errorlistReplacements_last_modified_dateOk 
def errorlistReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk 
def errorlistReplacements_typeOk 
def errorlistReplacements_displayNameOk 
def errorlistReplacements_itemNameSingleOk 
def errorlistReplacements_itemNamePluralOk 
def errorlistReplacements_descriptionOk 
def errorlistReplacements_shortDescriptionOk 
def errorlistReplacements_disabledOk 
def errorlistReplacements_user_msgOk 
def errorlistReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk 
def errorlistReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk 
def errorqlibExportValidations_statusOk 
def errorflatQuestions_moduleIdOk 
def errorflatQuestions_contentTypeOk 
def errorflatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk 
def errorflatQuestions_variableNameOk 
def errorflatQuestions_groupNameOk 
def errorflatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk 
def errorflatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk 
def errorflatQuestions_titleOk 
def errorflatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk 
def errorflatQuestions_isHiddenOk 
def errorflatQuestions_isSelectedOk 


item = values

if (! ( item._id ==~regexPattern)){
    IdOk = false
    errorIdOk = item._id
}
if (! ( item.qlib_questionnaire_id ==~regexPattern)){
    qlib_questionnaire_idOk = false
    errorqlib_questionnaire_idOk = item.qlib_questionnaire_id
}
if (! ( item.qlib_questionnaire_version_id ==~regexPattern)){
    qlib_questionnaire_version_idOk = false
    errorqlib_questionnaire_version_idOk = item.qlib_questionnaire_version_id
}
if (! ( item.language ==~regexPattern)){
    languageOk = false
    errorlanguageOk = item.language
}
if (! ( item.qlib_producttemplate_id ==~regexPattern)){
    qlib_producttemplate_idOk = false
    errorqlib_producttemplate_idOk = item.qlib_producttemplate_id
}
if (! ( item.wave_id ==~regexPattern)){
    wave_idOk = false
    errorwave_idOk = item.wave_id
}
if (! ( item.study_key ==~regexPattern)){
    study_keyOk = false
    errorstudy_keyOk= item.study_key
}
if (! ( item.last_updated ==~regexPattern)){
    last_updatedOk = false
    errorlast_updatedOk= item.last_updated
}
if (! ( qlibExportValidations.status ==~regexPattern)){
    qlibExportValidations_statusOk = false
    errorqlibExportValidations_statusOk= qlibExportValidations.status
}
// report result
assert IdOk : "id field does not match expected format. Error field:  " + errorIdOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert qlib_questionnaire_idOk : "qlib_questionnaire_id does not match expected format. Error field:  " + errorqlib_questionnaire_idOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert qlib_questionnaire_version_idOk : "qlib_questionnaire_version_id does not match expected format. Error field:  " + errorqlib_questionnaire_version_idOk  + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert languageOk : "language does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlanguageOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert qlib_producttemplate_idOk : "qlib_producttemplate_id does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorqlib_producttemplate_idOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert wave_idOk : "wave_id does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorwave_idOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert study_keyOk : "study_key does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorstudy_keyOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert last_updatedOk : "last_updated does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlast_updatedOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert qlibExportValidations_statusOk : "qlibExportValidations_status does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorqlibExportValidations_statusOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern



//Quotas arrray elements
for(i=0;i<quotas.size();i++){   
    
    item=quotas

if (! (item.id==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_idOk = false
            errorQuotas_idOk = item.id
         }
if (! (item.name==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_nameOk = false
            errorQuotas_nameOk = item.name
         }
if (! (item.title==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_titleOk = false
            errorQuotas_titleOk = item.title
         }
if (! (item.isSystem==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_isSystemOk = false
            errorQuotas_isSystemOk = item.isSystem
         }
if (! (item.portalDisplayAsPercents==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk = false
            errorQuotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk = item.portalDisplayAsPercents
         }
if (! (item.isDefaultQuota==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_isDefaultQuotaOk = false
            errorQuotas_isDefaultQuotaOk = item.isDefaultQuota
         }
if (! (item.hideQuotaInUI==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_hideQuotaInUIOk = false
            errorQuotas_hideQuotaInUIOk = item.hideQuotaInUI
         }
if (! (item.exclude_from_sample_definition==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk = false
            errorQuotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk = item.exclude_from_sample_definition
         }
if (! (item.setting_dependencies==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_setting_dependenciesOk = false
            errorQuotas_setting_dependenciesOk = item.setting_dependencies
         }
if (! (item.attributez==~regexPattern)) {
            Quotas_attributezOk = false
            errorQuotas_attributezOk = item.attributez
         }



// report result

assert Quotas_idOk : "Quotas_id does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_idOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_nameOk : "Quotas_name does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_nameOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_titleOk : "Quotas_title does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_titleOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_isSystemOk: "Quotas_isSystem does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_isSystemOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk: "Quotas_portalDisplayAsPercents does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_portalDisplayAsPercentsOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_isDefaultQuotaOk : "Quotas_isDefaultQuota does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_isDefaultQuotaOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_hideQuotaInUIOk : "Quotas_hideQuotaInUI does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_hideQuotaInUIOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk : "Quotas_exclude_from_sample_definition does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_exclude_from_sample_definitionOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_setting_dependenciesOk : "Quotas_setting_dependencies does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_setting_dependenciesOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert Quotas_attributezOk : "Quotas_attributez does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorQuotas_attributezOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern

}

//textReplacements arrray elements
for(i=0;i<textReplacements.size();i++){ 
    
    item=textReplacements

if (! (item.key==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_keyOk = false
            errortextReplacements_keyOk = item.key
         }
if (! (item.isHidden==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_isHiddenOk = false
            errortextReplacements_isHiddenOk = item.isHidden
         }
if (! (item.displayName==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_displayNameOk = false
            errortextReplacements_displayNameOk = item.displayName
         }
if (! (item.helpTextEnglish==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk = false
            errortextReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk = item.helpTextEnglish
         }
if (! (item.helpTextLocale==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk = false
            errortextReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk = item.helpTextLocale
         }
if (! (item.exampleTextEnglish==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk = false
            errortextReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk = item.exampleTextEnglish
         }
if (! (item.exampleTextLocale==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk = false
            errortextReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk = item.exampleTextLocale
         }
if (! (item.isDisabled==~regexPattern)) {
            textReplacements_isDisabledOk = false
            errortextReplacements_isDisabledOk = item.isDisabled
         }


// report result

assert textReplacements_keyOk : "textReplacements_key does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_keyOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_isHiddenOk : " textReplacements_isHidden does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_isHiddenOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_displayNameOk : " textReplacements_displayName does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_displayNameOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk : " textReplacements_helpTextEnglish does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_helpTextEnglishOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk : "textReplacements_helpTextLocale does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_helpTextLocaleOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk : "textReplacements_exampleTextEnglish does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_exampleTextEnglishOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk : "textReplacements_exampleTextLocale does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_exampleTextLocaleOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert textReplacements_isDisabledOk : "textReplacements_isDisabled does not match expected format. Error field: " + errortextReplacements_isDisabledOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern

}

//listReplacements arrray elements
for(i=0;i<listReplacements.size();i++){ 
    
    item=listReplacements

if (! (item.key==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_keyOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_keyOk = item.key
         }
if (! (item.maximumNumberOfValues==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk = item.maximumNumberOfValues
         }
if (! (item.maxAdNameLength==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk = item.maxAdNameLength
         }
if (! (item.completed==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_completedOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_completedOk = item.completed
         }
if (! (item.metRequirements==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_metRequirementsOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_metRequirementsOk = item.metRequirements
         }
if (! (item.last_modified_by==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_last_modified_byOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_last_modified_byOk = item.last_modified_by
         }
if (! (item.last_modified_date==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_last_modified_dateOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_last_modified_dateOk = item.last_modified_date
         }
if (! (item.minimumNumberOfValues==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk = item.minimumNumberOfValues
         }
if (! (item.type==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_typeOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_typeOk = item.type
         }
if (! (item.displayName==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_displayNameOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_displayNameOk = item.displayName
         }
if (! (item.itemNameSingle==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_itemNameSingleOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_itemNameSingleOk = item.itemNameSingle
         }
if (! (item.itemNamePlural==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_itemNamePluralOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_itemNamePluralOk = item.itemNamePlural
         }

if (! (item.shortDescription==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_shortDescriptionOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_shortDescriptionOk = item.shortDescription
         }
if (! (item.disabled==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_disabledOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_disabledOk = item.disabled
         }

if (! (item.user_msg==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_user_msgOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_user_msgOk = item.user_msg
         }

if (! (item.preDefinedListValues==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk = item.preDefinedListValues
         }

if (! (item.lastUsedCodeNumber==~regexPattern)) {
            listReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk = false
            errorlistReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk = item.lastUsedCodeNumber
         }


// report result

assert listReplacements_keyOk : "listReplacements_key does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_keyOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk : "listReplacements_maximumNumberOfValues does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_maximumNumberOfValuesOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk : "listReplacements_maxAdNameLength does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_maxAdNameLengthOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_completedOk : "listReplacements_completed does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_completedOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_metRequirementsOk : "listReplacements_metRequirements does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_metRequirementsOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_last_modified_byOk : "listReplacements_last_modified_by does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_last_modified_byOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_last_modified_dateOk : "listReplacements_last_modified_date does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_last_modified_dateOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk : "listReplacements_minimumNumberOfValues does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_minimumNumberOfValuesOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_typeOk : "listReplacements_type does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_typeOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_displayNameOk : "listReplacements_displayName does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_displayNameOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_itemNameSingleOk : "listReplacements_itemNameSingle does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_itemNameSingleOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_itemNamePluralOk : "listReplacements_itemNamePlural does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_itemNamePluralOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_shortDescriptionOk : "listReplacements_shortDescription does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_shortDescriptionOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_disabledOk : "listReplacements_disabled does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_disabledOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_user_msgOk : "listReplacements_user_msg does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_user_msgOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk : "listReplacements_preDefinedListValues does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_preDefinedListValuesOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert listReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk : "listReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumber does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorlistReplacements_lastUsedCodeNumberOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern


}

//flatQuestions arrray elements
for(i=0;i<flatQuestions.size();i++){    
    
    item=flatQuestions

if (! (item.moduleId==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_moduleIdOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_moduleIdOk = item.moduleId
         }
if (! (item.contentType==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_contentTypeOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_contentTypeOk = item.contentType
         }
if (! (item.isContentItemOptional==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk = item.isContentItemOptional
         }
if (! (item.variableName==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_variableNameOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_variableNameOk = item.variableName
         }
if (! (item.groupName==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_groupNameOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_groupNameOk = item.groupName
         }
if (! (item.qlibContentItemId==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk = item.qlibContentItemId
         }
if (! (item.dummyQuestion==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk = item.dummyQuestion
         }

if (! (item.repeaterItemSortOrder==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk = item.repeaterItemSortOrder
         }
if (! (item.isHidden==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_isHiddenOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_isHiddenOk = item.isHidden
         }
if (! (item.isSelected==~regexPattern)) {
            flatQuestions_isSelectedOk = false
            errorflatQuestions_isSelectedOk = item.isSelected
         }



// report result

assert flatQuestions_moduleIdOk : "flatQuestions_moduleId does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_moduleIdOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_contentTypeOk : "flatQuestions_contentType does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_contentTypeOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk : " flatQuestions_isContentItemOptional does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_isContentItemOptionalOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_variableNameOk : " flatQuestions_variableName does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_variableNameOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_groupNameOk : "flatQuestions_groupName does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_groupNameOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk : "flatQuestions_qlibContentItemId does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_qlibContentItemIdOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk : "flatQuestions_dummyQuestion does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_dummyQuestionOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk : "flatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrder does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_repeaterItemSortOrderOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_isHiddenOk : "flatQuestions_isHidden does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_isHiddenOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern
assert flatQuestions_isSelectedOk : "flatQuestions_isSelected does not match expected format. Error field: " + errorflatQuestions_isSelectedOk + " /RegEx:  " +regexPattern



}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Any way to reduce this massive code dump to a [mcve]?